# How does pglogical.replicate_ddl_command ensure that ddls are run at a consistent point?

Tags: postgresql, logical-replication, pglogical

From the pglogical readme:

> pglogical provides the pglogical.replicate_ddl_command function to allow DDL to be run on the provider and subscriber at a consistent point.

But how exactly does it ensure that that happens?

Looking through the codebase, I see that in [`pglogical_replicate_ddl_command`](https://github.com/2ndQuadrant/pglogical/blob/1ac225303ac8526355c7193fb8496c1780c7b324/pglogical_functions.c#L1755) they queue the command for replication:

```
/* Queue the query for replication. */
    queue_message(replication_sets, GetUserId(),
                  QUEUE_COMMAND_TYPE_SQL, cmd.data);
```

which then gets replicated as part of the `ddl_sql` replication set.

Upon receiving this sql string, the query gets extracted by [`handle_sql`](https://github.com/2ndQuadrant/pglogical/blob/REL2_x_STABLE/pglogical_apply.c#L1050) and then run by [`pglogical_execute_sql_command`](https://github.com/2ndQuadrant/pglogical/blob/1ac225303ac8526355c7193fb8496c1780c7b324/pglogical_functions.c#L1754).

But I don't see anywhere where they ensure that all previous data has been replicated, such that we are at a consistent point.. what am I missing here?